# MySQL column that auto generates data, longer than UUID

Tags: mysql, uuid, google-cloud-sql

My friend has the problem as shown below. He asked at StackOverFlow and there is no reply yet till now so I wish to help him to try the luck here. Thanks for everyone that helps.

"I would like to ask if its possible to set up a database table that has a column that auto generates random alphanumerical data that is longer that what UUID can do. I've been using UUID for a while now but I would like to have a longer string of random data in my columns, something similar to that of a token authenticator (around 300+ characters). So when I insert values in columns, this particular column will auto generate data by itself. Thanks in advance."

Quoted from Reuben Tan
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461771/mysql-column-that-auto-generates-data-longer-than-uuid

Comment: When you first insert the row?  Or whenever you update the row, too?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the pair of triggers `ON INSERT` and `ON UPDATE` that perform any desired transformations 'on the fly'

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myuuid_autoinserter` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `table` -- or BEFORE UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET loooonguuid = CONCAT(OLD.uuid, OLD.uuid, OLD.uuid, OLD.uuid)
  SET NEW.uuid = loooonguuid;
END
```

When you run some INSERT or UPDATE query on the `table` trigger will replace submitted value of the `uuid` by string stored in the `loooonguuid` variable.

Sure you can do as complex and randomized transformation as you want.